# Rails 4 - Delete rows from another table before updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code in my members controller:

```
def update
  @member.phone_numbers.destroy_all
  respond_to do |format|
    if @member.update(member_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @member, notice: 'Member was successfully updated' }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    end
  end
end
```

I have to delete existing records from **phone_numbers** before updating **members**, because the phone numbers must be inserted again (because of possible ordering changes and other reasons, but it does not matter).

The question is: It works, but if **members** fail to update, all the phone numbers will be already deleted.

What could be done to avoid the problem if the *@member.update* fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this into a helper method that wraps the statements into a transaction and call from the controller:

```
# Member Model
def delete_phone_numbers_and_update(params)
  Member.transaction do 
    phone_numbers.destroy_all
    update(params)
  end
end

# Controller
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @member.delete_phone_numbers_and_update(member_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @member, notice: 'Member was successfully updated' }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Minor correction: Use _Member.transaction do_ instead of _Member.transaction.do_

Answer (score 2):

You may consider marking the phone numbers for destruction instead of actually deleting them.

```
@member.phone_numbers.map(&:mark_for_destruction)
```

Then, when you do @member.update, it should do the update and the destruction of the associated phone numbers all at once. Here's the API for #mark_for_destruction: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#method-i-mark_for_destruction

Otherwise, you can look into setting up a transaction block. The API explains this well enough: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: The first approach didn't work, I can't mark **@members.phone_numbers** for destruction because it's where I have the current values that I have to save to the database. The second approach (transaction block) worked perfectly. Thank you.